# Passing windows AD machine authorization to linux VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, active-directory, kerberos

after trying for multiple hours to get this (not even necessary, but I somehow got lost in "the zone" and was committed) working without a single clue about the whole AD infrastructure, I'm out of ideas now.

I have a work win10 machine, which is registered to our Active Directory Domain, so it is already registered.
However, as I prefer working on Linux machines, I am running Linux inside a VM and basically use that for everyday work. And I just wanted the simple use case of having a Linux user which is synced to my AD user, just like it is in Windows.

I already got it set up so that the domain is correct in linux, I can resolve the domain with realm discover just fine. I can then get tickets with kinit / "online accounts" (ubuntu) functionality for my forename.surename account, but I can't get beyond that.

I played around with msktutil to get keytab files, but was always hitting some permission deadend.
I then played with joining the realm, like realm join -u forename.surname --computer-ou='' , which looked kinda good, after changing my linux hostname to the same one as my windows pc. But then that also failed, as the process of realm joining apparently requires setting of a random password for the computer account, for which I d'ont have the permissions.

Then I thought, hey, I already have all the tickets and everything on my windows host, can't I just pass that somehow to the linux VM? That's where I'm currently at, but it seems like I have to extract the tickets from the processor space, which I d'ont really think is an option on a work machine. Is there some other possibility I'm not seeing right now? Thanks for the help, I clearly have no idea what I'm doing, but hey, asking doesn't hurt right? :)

We also have ADFS implementation for SSO, but it seems like there is no implementation where I can just use the ADFS server to sign on / authenticate..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I just wanted the simple use case of having a Linux user which is synced to my AD user, just like it is in Windows.

Most "local" properties of a Windows account aren't really applicable to a single-user Linux system. Your home directory path will be different, your group memberships are irrelevant locally, the AD account probably doesn't have a field for your POSIX login shell provisioned so it'll default to /bin/sh, etc. The only thing worth "syncing" is Kerberos tickets for accessing various network services – which you can already do with `kinit` or `pam_krb5` (or GNOME Online Accounts, once v44.0 with the Kerberos fixes rolls out) without a full domain join.

> I already have all the tickets and everything on my windows host, can't I just pass that somehow to the linux VM? That's where I'm currently at, but it seems like I have to extract the tickets from the processor space, which I d'ont really think is an option on a work machine.

Windows stores its machine account password as an "LSA secret". If your administrator hasn't deployed the additional protection for LSASS.EXE (which, by the way, *just* got enabled by default for Windows 11 via last week's Windows Update), you can use one of several tools to dump LSA secrets and copy the machine password, then use `ktutil` to store it in the form of a keytab for /etc/krb5.keytab (and/or whatever other format SSSD or Winbind may require).

Note that both Windows and Linux (SSSD/Winbind) will change the machine password every ~30 days, so make sure to disable it at least on the Linux side. (In general that's what makes it a *bad* idea to use the same hostname between two systems – if you're not careful to disable all automatic machine password changes, you'll soon find yourself with a "Domain trust relationship failed" error upon trying to log in.)